# App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 5

Tags: android

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 5.

> Includes 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app.
>   Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More

My Gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.all.effect.photo.editor"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```

How can I build an **apk** which is compatible with both 64 bit and 32 bit architectures?

Answer (score 5):

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

change to

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
```

need to remove **x86** from ndk filters and my problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

defaultConfig {
...

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'

...
```

}

Please make sure this settings should be included in the defaultConfig. If there are external framework/library, then **ALSO** add in **cmake**